# Passing an expression tree as a parameter to another expression tree

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-trees

I have two expression trees defined like this:

```
private Expression<Func<TEntity, TPropertyResult>> PropertyAccessor { get; set; }
```

and

```
private Expression<Func<TPropertyResult, bool>> TestExpression { get; set; }
```

I need to create a new expression tree that will result in the equivalent of:

```
var expression = p => this.TestExpression(this.PropertyAccessor(p));
```

When using `Expression.Invoke(this.TestExpression, this.PropertyAccessor)`, I get the following error

> {"Expression of type
>   'System.Func`2[MyEntity,System.String]'
>   cannot be used for parameter of type
>   'System.String'"}

`TPropertyResult` is a string during my test.

I tried using `Expression.Call` or `Expression.Invoke`. No luck. What should I use?

Comment: What was the compiler error? Also, the code is not that readable. Are you sure that .Net 2.0 stuff is not enough for what you want to accomplish?

Comment: When using Invoke, it says: `{"Expression of type 'System.Func`2[MyEntity,System.String]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.String'"}`. That is when I try to specify a string as the `TPropertyResult`, but the problem is not limited to a string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this does what you are asking for:

```
Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> Combined
{
    get
    {
        var entity = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity));
        var pa = Expression.Invoke(PropertyAccessor, entity);
        var te = Expression.Invoke(TestExpression, pa);
        return (Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>) Expression.Lambda(te, entity);
    }
}
```

I tested this and it works as I would expect.

However, re-reading your original question (before my edits), I am beginning to get the impression that you asked the wrong question and that you probably don’t need expression trees. If all you need is *functions*, then you can use them without `Expression`:

```
private Func<TEntity, TPropertyResult> PropertyAccessor { get; set; }
private Func<TPropertyResult, bool> TestExpression { get; set; }
private Func<TEntity, bool> Combined
{
    get
    {
        return entity => TestExpression(PropertyAccessor(entity));
    }
}
```

Example of use:

```
// Set up the original functions
PropertyAccessor = entity => GenerateResult(entity);
TestExpression = result => result.IsCool();

// This stores a reference to the combined function
var fn = Combined;

// This actually evaluates the function
bool isCool = fn(myEntity);

// Alternatively, you could evaluate the function directly, without the variable
bool isCool = Combined(myEntity);
```

Comment: Wow thank you for this working answer. I got over my head by diving into expression. I guess that looking at ASP.NET MVC code makes you think that `Expression<T>` are needed everywhere.

Comment: Marc Gravell has a great article on InfoQ regarding how and why you should use Expression and some good concrete examples.

http://www.infoq.com/articles/expression-compiler

Comment: Thanks,I need to use it in `linq to sql` but get this error:  `The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.`   can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I found to do this is by using LinqKit (https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit)

With it you can actually do

```
var expression = p => this.TestExpression.Invoke(this.PropertyAccessor(p));
db.Users.Where(expression.Expand());
```

Expand comes with LinqKit and does the magic here, it allows EF to be able to do the translation to SQL despite having the Invoke in your expression.